# Is there a way to do Jupyter cell magic with R

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter and R on my Windows 8 laptop (64bit).

How do I run magic commands in a Jupyter notebook running with the R kernel.

Example:
I would like to run e.g.

```
%%latex
\sqrt{2}
```

but instead of formatted math this returns:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:1: unexpected SPECIAL
1: %%
    ^
```

The documentation for these functions is somewhat sparse and a lot of it has not been updated from the IPython documentation. Perhaps this functionality is not intended with r kernels.

Comment: If you just want to show latex formulas you could use a markdown cell. Have a look [here](http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Notebook%20Users%20Manual.ipynb#4.9-LaTeX-Math)

Comment: Thanks, but the LaTeX magic was just an example. Is interested in the availability of the while range of magics, but they not be included for the r kernel.

Comment: Magics are kernel specific and I can't find docs to create your own in other languages different than Python (IScala has some info). If you provide what you want to do maybe others can help you.

Comment: Another example would be to run a bit if python code in the R cell or vice versa.

Comment: have a look to [rPython](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/) (Python in R) and to [rpy2](http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/) (R in Python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic system is specific to the IPython kernel and does not exist in the R kernel. Currently there are no plans to integrate such a system (= we more or less decided not to start a magic system in IRkernel).

If you want to display markdown (or html/images/...) from r code, you can use the functions provided by the IRdisplay package, like:

```
library(IRdisplay)
display_markdown("**Strong Text**\n\nA formula: $\\sqrt{x}$")
```

Answer (score 2):

For Latex in Jupyter you do not need R magic. You can select cell type in the top panel with icons. Change "code" to "Markdown" and type:

```
$$
\sqrt{2}
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also missing this feature. The simple hack however is to create a python notebook, use [`rpy2`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/rmagic.html), and put `%%R` at the top of each cell. I guess you will also need to `%Rpush` and `%Rpull` all over the place to keep your variables going. It would be really nice to have this feature.